# vba access - Check if excel file is open

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Using VBA Access, I'm trying to edit the below code. So that it first checks if an excel file is open , if already open wait till file is closed then resume code? this needs to be done for each file 1,2,3.

1. Check if excel file is open
2. If open wait(Pause) till closed then resume code (Refresh table ,save, close)
3. Repeat process for the next file.

   ```
     Function RefreshExcelTables()

     Dim ExcelApp As Object

     Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

     ExcelApp.workbooks.Open "c:\test\Test_Sheet1.xlsb"
     ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.refreshall
     ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
     ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Close


     ExcelApp.workbooks.Open "c:\test\Test_Sheet2.xlsb"
     ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.refreshall
     ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
     ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Close


     ExcelApp.workbooks.Open "c:\test\Test_Sheet3.xlsb"
     ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.refreshall
     ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
     ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Close


     Set ExcelApp = Nothing


     End Function
   ```

Answer (score 0):

tested in Outlook

```
Sub Test()

Dim ExcelApp As Object
Dim X, X1

X = Array("c:\test\Test_Sheet1.xlsb", "c:\test\Test_Sheet2.xlsb")

For Each X1 In X
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ExcelApp = GetObject(X1).Application
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ExcelApp Is Nothing Then
        With ExcelApp.Workbooks(Right$(X1, Len(X1) - InStrRev(X1, "\")))
            .RefreshAll
            .Save
            .Close
    End With
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
    End If

Next X1
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried ur code but keep getting runtime error 9 ,out of range on line --- With ExcelApp.Workbooks(Right$(X1, Len(X1) - InStrRev(X1, "\")))